# jQuery realtime form validation

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am currently using $.blur(fn();) for form validation, but this only takes effect when the form field loses focus.  Is there a way of doing it on keypress to get realtime validation?  I suppose I could do the 'poll all fields every second' approach, but I am sure there must be a more elegant way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use $.keyup

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of other events you could use.  See here: http://docs.jquery.com/Events

I would recommend change or keypress or keydown.

Answer (score 2):

Since your using jQuery you should look into the [jQuery Validation Plugin](http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/). It will take care of the events for you. :)

Answer (score 2):

I hope this plugin helps

http://www.geektantra.com/2009/09/jquery-live-form-validation/